# removing quotations from ieeetr style of bibliography in Latex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am using ieetr style for my bibliography. This gives quotes for "the title of the article". I want to remove these quotes. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you proceed as follows.

- Locate the file `ieeetr.bst` in your TeX distribution (also linked [here](http://tug.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/ieeetr.bst)). Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `ieeetr-noquotes.bst`. (Don't edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly.
- Open `ieeetr-noquotes.bst` in a text editor. The editor you use for main tex file will do fine.
- In `ieeetr-noquotes.bst`, locate the function `format.title`. (In my copy of the file, the function starts on line 256.) In this function, locate the line

  ```
  { "``" title "t" change.case$ * ",''" * }
  ```

  Change it to

  ```
  { "" title "t" change.case$ "," * }
  ```
- Save the file `ieeetr-noquotes.bst` either in the directory that contains your main tex file or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the second option, you will probably also need to update the filename database of your TeX distibution.
- In the main tex file, change `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}` to `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr-noquotes}`. Then rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where can I exactly find ieeetr.bst ? This is not present in the folder where my tex file lies

Comment: @Raghupiska - The exact location of the file depends on your TeX distribution. Can you open a command window and type `kpsewhich ieeetr.bst`?